# How to remove ripple effect on clicking raised button flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have this dialog box and i have a question:

that when i click the close button, its giving this ripple effect which i dont want. I just want to pop the dialog box on pressed. This is the code

```
// Child 3 : Close Button
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(width * .62, height * .153, 0, 0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                splashColor: Colors.white,
                hoverColor: Colors.blue,
                elevation: 0,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  });
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
```

-->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHqWX.jpg

Comment: You can ask two question instead of nesting each-other where  two are not directly related

Comment: Yes i'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GestureDetector` that wont provide an extra ui decoration

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
  child: const Icon(
    Icons.close,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```

Also you can use `ElevatedButton` instead of `RaisedButton` while it is deprecated.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0),
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Icon(
    Icons.close,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```

More about [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and [`ElevatedButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) .